# Why does the frame around the camera flicker while running the BGE embedded player?

Tags: game-engine

Why does the black frame around the camera flicker when playing the game?

Here's a video showing what it looks like: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E5S9V1AtHI

Comment: Are you by any chance running on an intel embedded GPU? I've also seen this happening on an intel laptop with Intel GM965/GM960 integrated graphics on linux. Perhaps a hardware or driver issue? It shouldn't affect the game in any way, so I've just ignored it (or used the external player)

Comment: I can confirm, this is a typical Intel GPU/Driver issue.I had that at a couple of different laptops with similar effects.

Comment: I observed this as on a Laptop with Intel HD Graphics 520 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I quess this has something to do with the transparency of the area out of the camera region. By trial and error, I figured out that the flicker dissapears when you set the passepartout to 1.0.

[image]

However, in my case some of the text objects in the UI still flicker.

Answer (score 0):

you should turn on this option in user preferences

[image: turn on this option in user preferences]

Comment: Care to add some explanation as to why this will solve op's specific problem?